# MongoDB Template get only 1 row from duplicates

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, kotlin, mongodb-query, kotlin-coroutines

I have duplicate row values in my DB and would like to get only 1 from the API.
For example in db I have this kind of structure:

```
{
_id:39012fh19fh19bf21
"propertyId":12345,
"type":"STORE"
},
{
_id:69999999111
"propertyId":12345,
"type":"STORE"
}
```

The only difference is the MongoDB ID while other properties are the same.
I tried to use different aggregations with grouping but could not figure it out.

My code is quite simple currently it looks like this:

```
 val matchOperation = match(nestedCriteria) // Here are some criterias for basic filtering
        val sortDirection = Sort.Direction.ASC 
        val sortBy = "type"
        val page = PageRequest.of(...)

        val aggregation = newAggregation(
            matchOperation, sort(Sort.by(sortDirection, sortBy)), skip(page.offset), limit(
                page.pageSize.toLong()
            )
        )

        return mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "my_collection", MyCollectionVO::class.java)
            .asFlow()
```

I tried some things like this and a bunch of other combinations but it doesn't work :\

```
   val groupOperation = group("propertyId", "type")
            .count().`as`("count")
            .first("_id").`as`("uniqueDocId")

        val matchOperation = match(Criteria.where("count").gt(1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have the difference with _id. So you need to use [$group](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and return the first document in the group of documents with [$first](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#mongodb-group-grp.-first).

The query with Mongo Playground:
https://mongoplayground.net/p/29hiyjVLIop

```
var groupPipeline = group("$element").first("$$ROOT").as("doc");
var replaceRootPipeline = replaceRoot("doc");


var aggregation = newAggregation(groupPipeline, replaceRootPipeline);
mongoTemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "collection_Name", CollectionClass.class);
```